# show image in original size in material-ui

Tags: reactjs, image, resize, material-ui

I am developing an react web app, trying to show an image using Material-UI CardMedia tag of Card component

````
```
 <Card>
     <CardMedia
        component="img"
        height="100%"       
        image={'/images/' + selectedCode + '_poster.jpg'}
        title={selectedCode}
     />
</Card>
```
````

I want to show the image in original size, but Card always stretch my image to the same as the container's width which the image looks so terrible. How can I stop the code from resizing my image?

Comment: delete the height property

Comment: It works, thank you very much!

Comment: can you please leave a vote on the comment :)

Comment: @reemy I give you an up vote, your comment helped me :)